# Configure Kerberos for Windows Authentication in ASP.NET Core on IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, kerberos, windows-authentication, ntlm

How can I configure default Authentication method for Kerberos and prevent using NTLM? Just for Windows Authentication. No middleware needed. No multifactor authentication needed.
Startup class:

```
services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

Setup in IIS:
Windows Authentication - Enabled,
All other Authentication - Disabled.
Enabled Providers: Negotiate:Kerberos

Despite these settings, Fiddler shows NTLM in header. Any suggestions?

Comment: Fiddler is a man in the middle, so it can alter how things work. Try to use a tool like Wireshark to capture/analyze network packets, and that should tell you how exactly Windows authentication works under your settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that this is not programatically issue, rather than Windows Server config issue. The setup must be changed here:  Computer Configurations -> Policies -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> Security Options.